# is there a way to add current working directory/current git repo/branch in terminal prompt for Mac

Tags: macos, git, terminal, prompt

first time poster.

This came up in conversation at work this week...

Is there a way, when you connect to git remotely that you can get display current working directory/current git repo/branch in your terminal prompt?

Apparently, there are linux/vim scripts that exist for linux users, and I'd like to add this sort of shell script to my profile.

Currently I'm using some info from this page http://sos.blog-city.com/mac_os_x__bash_customize_your_terminal_prompt_a_little_color.htm to address some of this info locally.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a copy of the git completion script. You can get this from git itself, or if you have a Linux box handy you could even just copy it from there (it'll probably be `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`). Then, arrange for this to get "sourced" by bash. You can do this by adding something like this to your `.bashrc`:

```
. /usr/local/git-completion
```

(assuming you named the file `/usr/local/git-completion` on your Mac).

Finally, you'll want to adjust your prompt. Also in your `.bashrc`, add something like:

```
export PS1='[\w$(__git_ps1 "|%s")]\$ '
```

Here's a blog post (not by me) that talks about this (and some other related stuff) in more detail: http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/27983389/git-utilities-you-cant-live-without

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'll mess with it over the next couple of days and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I experimented with this after you pointed me in the right direction, my google searches got more refined results.

A lot of people point to the post you shared with me, like here: https://superuser.com/questions/31744/how-to-get-git-completion-bash-to-work-on-mac-os-x but I found some other jewels like these, which I didn't use but were informative: jeetworks.org/node/10 , jonmaddox.com/2008/03/13/show-your-git-branch-name-in-your-prompt/ .

I needed some different guidance on installing git.completion because I use homebrew which I found here: https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion which covers several ways to install it.

Finally, my bash/terminal has been a bit pokey so I upgraded to the latest bash with these instructions before I meshed with any of this: milkbox.net/brace_completion_snow_leopard_upgrading_bash/ and got some great speed improvement.

I ended up having to rebuild my profile script very carefully but with trail and error (because of differences between Bash 3 and 4, and some syntax errors)- now it looks great, and does the job.

Thanks again.

Sorry about above the security restraints of the site, restrict me (since I'm a newb) to 2 links to combat spam.

Answer (score 0):

You just need 2 steps to do it.

## Step.1:

Open **~/.bash_profile** in your favorite editor and add the following content to the bottom.

For me it is like

```
emacs ~/.bash_profile
```

## Step.2:

Add the following content to the bottom.

```
function git_branch {
git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'}

export PS1='\h:\w$(git_branch) \u\$'
```

## Done!

## P.s:

If you want your terminal colorful, try the following content.

```
export PS1 = '\[\e[1;39m\]\h:\w\[\e[01;39m\]$(git_branch) \[\e[01;39m\]$ \[\e[0m\]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get git branch/status info in your shell prompt is to use [powerline-shell](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell).

You can see what this looks like in this screenshot: 
[image]

The magenta/green bar is the current branch name. Its color indicates whether the working directory is clean. There are also markers that appear when there are untracked files, or when there are commits to be pulled-from/pushed-to the upstream remote.

Powerline-shell is compatible with bash, zsh, and fish.